# Restful-Authentication in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got this error "NoMethodError in Viewer#show" when I call login and logout page
     1: <%= @page.body.html_safe%>
Here is FULL TRACE

```
app/views/viewer/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_viewer_show_html_erb___528613762_33706236'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1069414350__process_action__324936555__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__522767632__call__754618940__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here the route.rb

```
 MyFirstApplicatin::Application.routes.draw do

 #get "viewer/show"
 resources :pages 
 resources :users
 resource :session
 resources :user_sessions 

 match ':name' => 'viewer#show' 

 match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login
 match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
 match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
 match "session" => 'users#show'

 get "/:name" => 'viewer#show', :as =>:view_page
 get "/:name" => 'logout#destroy'
 get "/:name" => 'login#new', :as =>:log_in
 get "pages/home"

 get "pages/resources"

 get "pages/services"

 get "pages/about"

 get "pages/contact"
 root :to => 'viewer#show', :name => 'home'

 end
```

Can someone help me please!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use gem "rails3-restful-authentication" with rails 3 support. just add

gem "rails3-restful-authentication", "~> 3.0.1"

in application Gemfile and it will support for rails 3 also.